# Scrape entire scrolling-load page with Python Requests

Tags: python-2.7, python-requests

Specifically, I'm trying to scrape this entire page, but am only getting a portion of it. If I use:

```
r = requests.get('http://store.nike.com/us/en_us/pw/mens-shoes/7puZoi3?ipp=120')
```

it only gets the "visible" part of the page, since more items load as you scroll downwards.

I know there are some solutions in PyQT such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37092265/repeatedly-scroll-to-the-bottom-of-a-page-using-pyqt-qwebkit), but is there a way to have python requests continuously scroll to the bottom of a webpage until all items load?

Answer (score 3):

You could monitor page network activity with browser development console (F12 - Network in Chrome) to see what request does the page do when you scroll down, use that data and reproduce the request with `requests`. As an alternative, you can use `selenium` to control a browser programmatically to scroll down until page is ended, then save its HTML.

I guess I found the right request

```
Request URL:http://store.nike.com/html-services/gridwallData?country=US&lang_locale=en_US&gridwallPath=mens-shoes/7puZoi3&pn=3
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
Remote Address:87.245.221.98:80
```

## Request Headers

```
Provisional headers are shown
Accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Referer:http://store.nike.com/us/en_us/pw/mens-shoes/7puZoi3?ipp=120
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36
X-NewRelic-ID:VQYGVF5SCBAJVlFaAQIH
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
```

Seems that query parameter `pn` means the current "subpage". But you still need to understand the response correctly.